# Не отображаются полосы прогресса

Tags: html, css, html5, progress-bar

Не могу понять, где ошибка в коде, почему не отображается полоса прогресса?

```css
.box-skills_item {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.box-skills_item-content {
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.about-wrap-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
}

.about-wrap-content_icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-right: 29px;
  flex: none;
  border: 2px solid #f39c12;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.about-wrap-content_text h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.about-wrap-content_text p {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.about-wrap-content_text .about-text {
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.bars-line {
  height: 10%;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

.bars-line div {
  height: 10%;
  background: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-skills_item box-skills_item-content">
  <div class="about-wrap-content">
    <div class="about-wrap-content_icon">
      <span class="icon-params"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="about-wrap-content_text">
      <h6>Our Skills</h6>
      <p>Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-bars">
  
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span>/ 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span>/ 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span>/ 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span> / 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box-skills_item {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.box-skills_item-content {
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.about-wrap-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
}

.about-wrap-content_icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-right: 29px;
  flex: none;
  border: 2px solid #f39c12;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.about-wrap-content_text h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.about-wrap-content_text p {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.about-wrap-content_text .about-text {
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.bars-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bars-line {
  height: 10px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.bars-line div {
  height: 10px;
  background: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-skills_item box-skills_item-content">
  <div class="about-wrap-content">
    <div class="about-wrap-content_icon">
      <span class="icon-params"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="about-wrap-content_text">
      <h6>Our Skills</h6>
      <p>Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-bars">
  
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span>/ 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span>/ 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span>/ 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="bars-title">
        Design <span> / 88%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bars-line">
        <div style="width: 88%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```